# Writing a loop for the sparc machine

Tags: assembly, sparc

I am trying to write the following code for the sparc machine.

```
y=(x-7)(x-11) for the range 0<=x<=10
```

and I want to print out the following code like this `for input of x=0 output y=77` and so on up to ten.

I managed to make the loop. But my problem is getting the output printed out.

```
       /*
     This program will compute y=(x-7)(x-11)
     for the range 0<=x<=10
    */

     /*
    these are the variables
    */

.section ".data"

mystring:.asciz "for input of x=%d and output y=%d"

  define(a1,7)

 define(a2,11)

define(x_r,l0)
define(x_r,l1)
.section ".text"

main:
save %sp,-96,%sp
clr %x_r

loop:
 sub %x_r,a1,%o0 !(x-a1)

sub %x_r,a2,%o1 !(x-a2)
call .mul
 nop

  mov %o0,%y_r
  add %x_r,1,%x_r

  cmp %x_r,10
 ble loop
  nop

 ret
 restore
```

I know I have to print something like this on my code but Im not sure where.

```
 set mystring,%o0
 move %x_r,%o1
 move %y_r,%o2
 call printf
 nop
```

THe output I get now is

for input of x=0  output y=77     for input of x=1  output y=60        for input of                         x=2  output y=45             for input of x=3  output y=32        for input of x=4  output y=21               for input of x=5  output y=12        for input of x=6  output y=5          for input of x=7  output y=0         for input of x=8  output y=-3        for input of x=9  output y=-4          for input of x=10  output y=-3

I would like it like this

for input of x=0 output y=77
for input x=1 output y=60
......
......
for input x=10 y=-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I saw SPARC assembly last time.  Nowadays CPUs are either x86 or ARM.  My knowledge about SPARC assembly is quite rusty...

1. The second alias is a typo, isn't it?  I guess it was meant for `y_r`

   ```
   define(x_r,l0)
   define(x_r,l1)
   ```
2. With `mov %o0,%y_r` you store the result of multiplication into `%y_r`.  Whereas the next line `add %x_r,1,%x_r` is `++x` in C.  So `printf` should be invoked between these two.

Comment: yes that makes sense, thanks for your response it works, but is there anyway to make the output show up vertical instead of horizontal when printed

Comment: Can you "edit" your question post to add (1) the output you get as of now, and (2) the desired output?